# Integrating $\int x \csc^2(\,\ln(x)\,)\,dx$

Tags: integration, trigonometry, logarithms

What is this integral?

$$\int x \csc^2(\,\ln(x)\,)\,dx$$

I haven't found any solution yet. It's the same as this one

$$\int \frac{x}{\sin^2(\,\ln x\,)}\,dx$$

So, how can I understand this integral in order to solve it?

Comment: It can be expressed by a Hyberbolic function

Comment: How so? is there a list of integrals of hyperbolic functions that could help me?

Comment: See here $$x^2 (-\cot (\log
   (x)))-\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}\right) x^2
   \left((1+i) \, _2F_1\left(-i,1;1-i;x^{2
   i}\right)+x^{2 i} \, _2F_1\left(1,1-i;2-i;x^{2
   i}\right)\right)$$

Comment: Oh, thank you Dr., but I still have two questions. First, how did you solve it? and second, is there an answer without complex numbers?

Comment: I haven't solved it, it was WA

Comment: You can use Google, i wish you good luck

Comment: Yes, I wanted like something to help me to understand that integral, anyways, thank you very much for your time! It's very appreciated

Comment: The antiderivative can be expressed in a simpler form than the WA result: $(-1+i) x^{2+2 i} \, _2F_1\left(1-i,2;2-i;x^{2 i}\right)$

Answer (score 2):

A start

Recall that $$\sin x=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$$
So of course $$\sin\log x=\frac{x^i-x^{-i}}{2i}$$
$$\sin^2\log x=-\frac{(x^i-x^{-i})^2}{4}$$
Hence $$I=\int x\csc^2\log x\,\mathrm dx=-4\int\frac{x}{(x^i-x^{-i})^2}\mathrm dx$$
$$I=-4\int\frac{x}{x^{2i}+x^{-2i}-2}\mathrm dx$$
Which may be a little easier...